# Struggling to get desired return

Tags: mysql, left-join

I'm relatively new to SQL, but am generally a quick learner and this particular query has stumped me for a few days. Any help would be beyond appreciated at this point.

When I run the below query, I only return rows where there exists a statusdatetime (the agent logged in that day). I need to return a row even when the agent didn't log in but was scheduled. How can I change this query to return a NULL for that. I thought the left join would work.

```
DECLARE @startDate datetime
DECLARE @endDate datetime

SET @startDate = GETDATE()
SET @endDate = GETDATE()

SET @startDate = CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(varchar(11),@startDate, 111 ) + ' 00:00:00', 111)
SET @endDate = CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(varchar(11),@endDate, 111 ) + ' 23:59:59', 111)


Begin

Create table #boris5table(
Firstname varchar(50),
lastname varchar (50),
username varchar (50),
starttime datetime,
loggedintime datetime,
variation int)

End


Insert into #boris5table (Firstname, lastname, username, starttime, loggedintime, variation)
Select firstname, lastname, userid,
(cast(DATEADD(MINUTE, (-300 +
(select min(startoffset) from [dbo].[IO_ScheduleInterval]
Where activitytypeid = '0000000000000000000004'
and PaidTime = '1'
and f1.agentid = f2.agentid
and ScheduleID = f1.scheduleid)), StartDateTimeUTC) as datetime)),
case when exists (select count(*), statusdatetime from [dbo].[AgentActivityLog] Where StatusDateTime between @startdate and @enddate Group by StatusDateTime) then min(statusdatetime)
Else NULL
End as LoggedInTime,
DATEDIFF(minute, (cast(DATEADD(MINUTE, (-300 +
(select min(startoffset) from [dbo].[IO_ScheduleInterval]
Where activitytypeid = '0000000000000000000004'
and PaidTime = '1'
and f1.agentid = f2.agentid
and ScheduleID = f1.scheduleid)), StartDateTimeUTC) as datetime)), 

case when exists (select statusdatetime from [dbo].[AgentActivityLog] Where  StatusDateTime between @startdate and @enddate and f3.UserId = f2.UserName) then min(statusdatetime)
Else 'NULL' END)
as 'Variation (minutes)'

From [I3_IC].[dbo].[IO_Schedule] as f1
left join [dbo].[IO_Agent] as f2 on f1.AgentID = f2.AgentID and (CAST(DATEADD(hour, - 5, f1.StartDateTimeUTC) as date)) between @startdate and @enddate
left join [dbo].[Individual] as f4 on f2.UserName = f4.WebLogin and LastName <> '-'
left join [dbo].[AgentActivityLog] as f3 on f2.UserName = f3.UserId and (CAST(DATEADD(hour, -1, f3.StatusDateTime) as date)) between @startdate and @enddate


Group by firstname, lastname, f2.UserName, ScheduleID, f1.AgentID, f2.AgentID, StartDateTimeUTC, f3.UserId



Select *
From #boris5table

drop table #boris5table
```

Comment: Why do you have `join` conditions both in the `from` and the `where`?  That is probably the root of your problem.  Put `join` conditions in the `on` clause where they belong.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, you are absolutely correct about that redundancy, however that doesn't solve the issue for me. The main issue is where I can put the (CAST(DATEADD(hour, -1, f3.StatusDateTime) as date)) between startdate and enddate part of the where clause so it doesn't limit my return, correct?

Comment: Any `where` condition on any table except the first is going to turn the `left join`s into `inner join`s.  You need to put all those conditions in the `on` clause.

Comment: I did that, but get the following error: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time to character string. I've updated my query above. Any idea where that error is derived from?